# Pops and Clicks with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I've been trying to make a digital synthesizer with the Web Audio API and i've hit a bit of a roadblock.  I'm trying to add an envelope to a polyphonic synth and I can't seem to get it right.  I've tried pretty much every combination of linearRamptoValueAtTime, exponentialRamptoValueAtTime, setTargetAtTime, etc... And I still end up with these annoying pops and clicks.  I feel like I've read every tutorial and post on this topic but i'm obviously doing something wrong.

Here's the code for my attack and release at the moment.

Attack:

```
let osc1Vol;
keyboard.keyDown = function(note, freq) {
    let now = audioCtx.currentTime;
    const osc1 = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    if (gainNodeTable[freq]) {
    osc1Vol = gainNodeTable[freq];
    osc1Vol.gain.cancelScheduledValues(now);
    osc1Vol.gain.setValueAtTime(osc1Vol.gain.value, now);
  } else {
    osc1Vol = audioCtx.createGain();
    osc1Vol.gain.setValueAtTime(0, now);
  }
    osc1.connect(osc1Vol);
    osc1.type = osc1wave.value;
    osc1.frequency.value = (freq * octaveTable[osc1octave.value]);
    oscillators[freq] = osc1;
    gainNodeTable[freq] = osc1Vol;
    osc1Vol.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    osc1Vol.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1.0, (now + parseInt(attack.value)));
  osc1.start();
};
```

release:

```
keyboard.keyUp = function (note, freq) {
    const now = audioCtx.currentTime;
    const gain = gainNodeTable[freq].gain.value;
    gainNodeTable[freq].gain.cancelScheduledValues(now);
    gainNodeTable[freq].gain.setValueAtTime(gain, now)
    gainNodeTable[freq].gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.0001, now + parseInt(decay.value));
    oscillators[freq].stop(now + parseInt(decay.value));
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just running it through a filter to get rid of those frequencies.